# Magento 2:- How to add order export feature to seller dashboard?

Tags: sales-order, csv, export, magento2.2.4

I'm using Marketplace and there is separate dashboard for each seller from where seller can manage their sections e.g-products,stores,orders etc.

for now,on order grid seller can't export the order but we want to add order export here.

[image]

As i tried and added following code one by one on the marketplace UI component file marketplace_orders_listing.xml under the "listingToolbar" tag but it doesn't works:-

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
```

**OR**

```
 <exportButton name="export_button">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">marketplace_orders_listing.marketplace_orders_listing.orders_columns.order_id</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
     </exportButton>
```

OR

```
<exportButton name="export_button"/>
```

All three above code are adding a Export button:-

[image]

But after clicking on export button,**it's redirecting me on 404 Page** so please help me to add this feature.

Expected Result:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used following code on the file:-

**app/code/NameSpace/mnarketplace/view/frontend/ui_component/mnarketplace_orders_listing.xml**

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">marketplace/order_export/gridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">marketplace/order_export/gridToXml</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">marketplace_orders_listing.marketplace_orders_listing.orders_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
```

And it's working for me!

To export CSV,I'm calling a controller "marketplace/order_export/gridToCsv",and everything is working fine.

Thanks!!!